# Replacing a list of words in MS Word

Tags: ms-word, str-replace

In MS Word, I would like to do a word-to-word translation which involves a list (MS Excel or anything else) of professional vocab with a translated vocab, while grammar is ignored.

Let say, I have a million-word DOC document. And I have created a list of vocabs (or strings) that Google Translation and others softwares cannot translate with respect to a certain profession. And I have > 1000 words in the list (XLS).

```
        A (Vocab)     B (Translation)

1       qwertyuiop    ABC

2       asdfghjkl     DEF

3       zxcvbnm       XYZ
```

What I want is, if I check through the DOC document, where-ever I find "asdfghjkl" (which is A3), it would be replaced into "DEF" (which is B3).

In MS Word, I tried "Replace All" in Ctrl + F, but I have to go through 1000 times if I have 1000 vocabs to be translated. How can I, within MS Word (VBA??) or from a software, replace those vocabs with ease??

Thanks a million!! =)

Comment: What have you tried in VBA so far? It's a lot easier to help with specific code.

Comment: Sadly, I am not familiar with VBA. What I have found are VBA codes which can search and replace one word, in turn I have to run for 1000 times again, which is no better than "Replace All" in Ctrl + F.

Comment: I believe this free tool (http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/word_tip_pages/vba_find_and_replace.html) is what you are looking for (found it linked from this page - http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?33598-How-to-find-and-replace-multiple-words-at-one-time - which looks like the same type of request). The download link is at the bottom of page - I strongly suggest making a backup of your files before playing with VBA. Hope this helps. (I did post this as an answer but as I can't post any of the code I have changed it to a comment).